Real const shared instance
We have a data object in our code that is relatively expensive to create, but is required by several other classes, so we prefer to have a shared object. Since we initialize a file format depending on the data object, this object must remain unchanged.
I tried it with a std::shared_ptr containing a const instance. But it seems the instance is not really const for all.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Data
{
    int value = 0;
};

class DataHolder
{
public:
    DataHolder(std::shared_ptr<const Data> data)
        : m_data(std::move(data))
    {        
    }

    void printValue() const
    {
        std::cout << m_data->value << '\n';
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<const Data> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    auto data = std::make_shared<Data>();
    data->value = 5;

    DataHolder dataHolder(data);
    dataHolder.printValue();

    data->value = 10;
    dataHolder.printValue();

    return 0;
}

Is there any variant where a truly constant object is created and passed at runtime?

"Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Then don't do that!" Just don't retain the original non-const pointer. DataHolder dataHolder(std::make_shared<Data>(Data{5}));.

Well since data lives as long as main, you don't need a "shared" instance at all. Just pas a referecnce to data to dataHolder (which will have a shorter lifetime) and all is fine. So you can then use const Data data; as first line of your main. (this is usually how dependency injection should work anyway, just know the lifetime of your objects up front)

@PepijnKramer This is presumably a minimized version, and in the general case the lifetime of the dataHolder extends beyond the end of the function that created it. OP: auto data = std::make_shared<const Data>(); makes you a shared pointer to a const Data that nobody can mutate, if that's what you wanted.

@RaymondChen Fair enough :) But this is the basis I build very large systems on (use the lifetime as specified by the order of instantiation in main). The shared_ptr case usually only comes into play when I start adding threads and lifetimes are not always knowable at design time.

"I tried it with a std::shared_ptr containing a const instance." -- You claim this, but in your code I see a std::shared_ptr containing a non-const instance (the data in your main function). Why not const everywhere, since you want the data to be constant everywhere?

@RaymondChen Exactly, it's a very simplified version. It's obvious that you can add a const everywhere. My intention here is to design the API in such a way that developer errors are already prevented by design (if you not intentionally bypass it e.g. via a const_cast). The issue with the std::shared_ptr<const Data> construct is actually that you can assign a std::shared_ptr<Data> to it and are not forced to pass a real constant object.

As an example: You have a GUI that holds a data instance that can be modified via the GUI. If this instance is now to be used in the backend (e.g. as the basis for a file writer), it should be explicitly converted into a const instance, e.g. via the move constructor. So there should be a compiler error if you contradict this, e.g. by creating the file writer while the user can still change the data object via the GUI.

That's not expressible in C++. const doesn't mean "nobody can modify it, not even by other non-const references to the same object". It just means "nobody can modify it through this reference." What you can do is create a new type ConstData with a single member const Data data,. Now, even if you have a non-const reference to a ConstData, you can't modify it because the data member is const. Basically, you're asking for an immutable type, and the way to do that is to make a class with no mutable members.

@SunBlack "it should be explicitly converted into a const instance" -- You can do that. It's called the copy constructor (possibly the move constructor, depending on why you don't claim unique ownership). Why are you allowing the code that constructs DataHolder to retain ownership of the data that is used by DataHolder?

Ok thanks to you all. Since C++, according to the comments until now, does not yet offer a suitable concept for this, I have now solved it using a wrapper (see my initial post). I find it a bit ugly, because now every time a "dummy" member has to be accessed, but well... If someone has a nicer solution where you don't notice the wrapper...

You have your answer right here — see below! It doesn't involve an ugly wrapper. If you posted your answer as answer (as this site intends to be used), I'd downvote it, but since it's now a part of the question, I'll just downvote the question instead.

@anatolyg The solution proposed by @yakk-adam-nevraumont does not solve the issue, as you can pass a std::make_shared<Data> to DataHolder, even if you expect a std::make_shared<const Data>. In other words, it is only guaranteed that the Data object is constant within DataHolder, but not that nobody can change it from outside.
I have moved the solution to a separate post, as you requested, even though I have often seen the solution included in the initial post on this platform.

Solution
In case someone else is looking for the same thing, here is the solution. Since C++ offers nothing in this direction so far, it seems that only a wrapper remains as a solution.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Data
{
    int value = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct ConstValueHolder
{
    ConstValueHolder(T value)
        :  constValue(std::move(value))
    {        
    }

    const T constValue;
};

class DataHolder
{
public:
    DataHolder(std::shared_ptr<ConstValueHolder<Data>> data)
        : m_data(std::move(data))
    {        
    }

    void printValue() const
    {
        std::cout << m_data->constValue.value << '\n';
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<ConstValueHolder<Data>> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    auto valueHolder = std::make_shared<ConstValueHolder<Data>>(Data{5});
    // valueHolder->constValue.value = 5; // compiler error

    DataHolder dataHolder(valueHolder);
    dataHolder.printValue();

    return 0;
}


Well constValue.value does not exist for the template type T. I think that is why you get a compilation error. Am I correct ?

auto data = std::make_shared<Data const>();

once you do this, any attempt to edit *data results in undefined behavior.
If you need to first make a Data object then make it const, do this:
Data tmp;
tmp.value = 5;
auto data = std::make_shared<const Data>(std::move(tmp)); // move is just for efficiency.

The lines of code that attempt to edit the contents of data will fail to compile.  If you delete them your program runs "correctly".
If you choose to edit tmp instead, then dataHolder.printValue(); won't reflect any changes.

Yes, I am aware of that. I was asking about the fact that e.g. DataHolder dataHolder(std::make_shared<Data>(...)); should already give a compile error, i.e. if someone does not use DataHolder dataHolder(std::make_shared<const Data>(...));

@SunBlack A pointer to const data can be initialized via a pointer to non-const data.  A pointer to const data is a view of data that is const, not a guarantee that the data pointed to is immutable.  It is possible you misunderstand what the const keyword means in C++?  It is a common misunderstanding.
